# OpenLDAP Filtering Users that are part of Groups of Groups

Tags: centos, ldap, centos6, openldap

LDAP Configuration:

```
MemberOf Overlay is enabled
```

- Users are part of an organizationalUnit called People.
- Each user is a "memberOf" a role. For example, a user in their role at a company is a "SeniorDeveloper" or a "Director" or a "QAAnalyst". These roles are of objectClass "groupOfNames".
- Each role is a "memberOf" a functional group. For example, there is a "groupOfNames" called "productionServers" and it has other "groupOfNames" as members. The groups "SeniorDeveloper" and "QAAnalyst" are part of the "productionServers" group.

**I need a query that says, get all the users that are part of the "productionServers" group.**

This filter returns the groups that are members of "productionServers":

```
(&
    (memberOf=cn=prodServersSudo,ou=Function,dc=example,dc=com)
)
```

[image]

Comment: If you think I'm going about this the wrong way, please tell me what you think the correct way would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single LDAP query that can do what you want.

You could:

- implement recursive the logic yourself via multiple calls
  Postfix does this. See: [ldap_table(5)](http://www.postfix.org/ldap_table.5.html#special_result_attribute)
  `special_result_attribute`
- run a cron job on a system that keeps flatter groups in order
  `Active Directory` does something similar with `adminCount`

At this time I don't recall if `sssd` will work with hereditary groups.  You'll want to set `ldap_schema = rfc2307bis` to test, along with making your `groupOfNames` a `posixGroup`.